# Encoding problems when reading XML from a Russian website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, encoding

I`m get values in xml, from a Russian bank's web service (source: http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp)

**My ASP.NET code:**

```
<%@ Page   Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4.WebForm1" CodePage="65001"  %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="volutes" runat="server" >
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#df5015" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**My C# code:**

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp");
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            String content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.LoadXml(content);


            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
            XmlNodeList nodeList = xml.SelectNodes("/ValCurs/Valute");
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {
                DataRow dtrow = dt.NewRow();
                dtrow["Name"] = node["Name"].InnerText;
                dtrow["Value"] = node["Value"].InnerText;
                dt.Rows.Add(dtrow);
            }
            volutes.DataSource = dt;
            volutes.DataBind();
```

**Оn the results page I`m see:**

```
 Name                                 Value
������������� ������    46,0642
```

Why?

Comment: check if the name appears correctly inside the `String content`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the correct encoding for your `StreamReader` and pass that in the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143456%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), else the reader will use UTF-16 LE by default:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( stream
                                             , Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251")
                                             )
      )
{
}
```